# Find img src without with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

HTML source:

```html
<div id="Awesome" class="vertical">
<img src="image1.jpg" data-count="1"><br>
<img src="image2.jpg" data-count="2"><br>
```

I'm trying to get the `src` value from above.

```
var frame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Awesome\"]/img[1]")).GetAttribute("src");
```

but I just got OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException.

And there was a problem here:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"Awesome\"]/img[1]")
```

Comment: Seems to me that you are looking for the 'src' attribute in the DIV and not on the IMG. Please give an ID to the image and try getting it directly to check if the XPath is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a few ways.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='Awesome']/img[1]")).GetAttribute("src");
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='Awesome']/img[2]")).GetAttribute("src");

driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='Awesome']/img[@data-count='1']")).GetAttribute("src");
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='Awesome']/img[@data-count='2']")).GetAttribute("src");
```